# Add selected tag using HTML Helper DropDownListFor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html-helper

I'm using ASP.NET HTML helpers to generate and HTML dropdown list. So basically I have the following code:

```js
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DropDownListName, new List<SelectListItem> {
           new SelectListItem{Text="Option 1", Value="1",Selected=true},
           new SelectListItem{Text="Option 2", Value="2", Selected = false},
           new SelectListItem{Text="Option 3", Value="3", Selected = false}},
           new { @class = "myClass" });
```

The Helper does generate and HTML dropdown with the corresponding options, the problem is that I would like to add the "selected" attribute to the HTML tag corresponding to the selected value to the dropdown and this is not generated.

Actually my final goal is to have a way to get the selected option in my JavaScript and here is the code I was using to do that before using an HTML Helper:

```js
var _selectedObjectId = parseInt($('#selectObject :selected').attr("id"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// To get the selected item in jQuery / Javascript:
var selected = parseInt( $("#DropDownListName").val() );

// To get the selected <option> HTML element:
var selectedOption = $("#DropDownListName option:selected");

// To get custom attributes other than the **value** (as in <option value="1"></option> then:
var id = selectedOption.attr("id");

// The story goes
```